# return value of select query using oracle sql plus in korn shell

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus, ksh

i use below code to return value from oracle. But unable to get 
 the desired result.

**EDIT: posting the function with actual values.**

```
function Check_Job_Info 
{
    print "Start week -Check_Job_Info : $start_week " 1>&2;
    print "End Week - Check_Job_Info : $end_week " 1>&2;
    JOBNUM=`sqlplus -s username/pwd@db <<EOF
    SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
    SELECT job_number FROM jobs_list WHERE start_week = 1347 and end_week = 1347 ;
    EXIT;
    EOF`
    print "Job Exists  : $JOBNUM " 1>&2;
}
```

the value printed are also the same as the hardcoded value

The problem is the value returned doesnt actually exist in the table.So it returns job_number say 1000. and when i do a select using 1000 it returns no rows. the value for start_week and end_week are numeric

```
JOB_NUMBER                                NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 TYPE                                      NOT NULL NUMBER(1)
 START_WEEK                                         NUMBER(5)
 END_WEEK                                           NUMBER(5)
```

What could possibly be wrong in the query? trying to figure this out for the last 2 days.

Basically doing a checking whether a row exists and if not insert new row.

Comment: What do you mean by `the value returns doesnt exist`? Do you get an error message? Also, please provide the DDL statement for jobs_list, the contents of the table and the parameter values you provide for start_week and end_week.

Comment: Firstly, your connection string is incorrect. It should be `sqlplus -s username/password@db`.

Comment: got misplaced while changing in the SO post

Comment: give the complete shell script and also the output of the query when you run it manually.

Comment: added the full function to the post

Comment: Apologies... There are 2 database with almost same name and it all got messed up. Can i remove the question?

Answer (score 1):

The order of parameter in sqlplus command is wrong. It should be `username/password@db` . Try connecting to db manually and you will understand.

```
JOBNUM=`sqlplus -s username/password@db <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
SELECT job_number FROM jobs_List WHERE start_week = $start_week and end_week = $end_week ;
EXIT;
EOF`
```

Comment: username/pwd is correct . when i changed in the post. it got misplaced. corrected in the question

Comment: what do you get when you run the query in db?

Comment: when run in db job_number returned is different than what i get from korn

Comment: that may be because the variables `$start_week` and `$end_week` values. You gotta edit the question with complete shell script and db output. Try printing the variable values at each step (before the sqlplus command and after it) to see where are you getting it wrong.

Comment: replaced with actual values but no change. Could this be some transaction/session related issues? havent used any transaction in the script. and use same user while running the script as well as in sqlplus window